# Problem with extract() with custom shortcode

Tags: functions, customization, shortcode

I'm trying to add an image with this shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('img_portfolio', 'add_img_portfolio');

function add_img_portfolio($atts){
shortcode_atts(array(
  'url' => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/popco/images/services/starter-page/img-placeholder.jpg',
  'height' => 'auto'
), $atts);
extract($atts);
return '<img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="'.$url.'" alt="" width=100% height="'.$height.'">';
  }
```

And getting this error:

```
Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given
```

Knowing that this same function pattern works in another shortcode i've made.

Thanks

Comment: You should avoid using `extract` for security/readability/usability reasons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no attributes are used on the shortcode, then `$atts` will be a string, so you can't use `extract` on it. Part of your problem is that you're not using `shortcode_atts` correctly. You need to assign the value of `shortcode_atts` back to `$atts`. That will ensure that `$atts` is an array with all the correct keys.

```
add_shortcode('img_portfolio', 'add_img_portfolio');

function add_img_portfolio($atts){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
      'url' => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/popco/images/services/starter-page/img-placeholder.jpg',
      'height' => 'auto'
    ), $atts);
    extract($atts);
    return '<img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="'.$url.'" alt="" width=100% height="'.$height.'">';
}
```

But honestly, don't use `extract()`, it's considered a bad practice, because your code ends up with a bunch of variables that aren't apparently assigned anywhere. Just use `$atts` as an array:

```
function add_img_portfolio($atts){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
      'url' => 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/popco/images/services/starter-page/img-placeholder.jpg',
      'height' => 'auto'
    ), $atts);

    return '<img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="'.$atts['url'].'" alt="" width=100% height="'.$atts['height'].'">';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and the advice it works perfectly now!

Comment: ps: we should also remember to escape these attributes in the output