# Wordpress Code Standards and Working $link Parameters In Shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I Have this snippet code,

```
add_shortcode( 'parent-child', 'taxonomy_hierarchy' );
function taxonomy_hierarchy( $atts ){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'link' => true,
        'taxonomy' => 'property_city'
    ), $atts, 'parent-child' ) );

    global $post;
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );

    /* You can pass conditions here to override
     * $link based on certain conditions. If it's
     * a single post, current user is editor, etc.
     */

    ob_start();
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
        if( $term->parent != 0 ){
            $parent_term = get_term( $term->parent, $taxonomy );
            echo ($link != false) ? sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>, ', esc_url( get_term_link($parent_term) ), $parent_term->name ) : "{$parent_term->name}, " ;
        }

        echo ($link != false) ? sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_term_link($term) ), $term->name ) : $term->name ;
    }   

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

This will allow you to get the following results:
usage

```
**[parent-child]**
• <a href="#">New York</a>
• <a href="#">New York</a>, <a href="#">Manhattan</a>

**[parent-child link="true"]**
• <a href="#">New York</a>
• <a href="#">New York</a>, <a href="#">Manhattan</a>

**[parent-child link="false"]**
• New York
• New York, Manhattan

[parent-child link="false" taxonomy="some_other_taxonomy"]
• Top Level Term
• Top Level Term, Child Level Term
```

Everything works fine and displays as expected! just...my  parameters  do not work.

I failed to get **[parent-child link="false"]**  work..
During my research on how shortcodes work, I came across these posts,

[link1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278708/problem-with-extract-with-custom-shortcode)
[link2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99603/what-does-extract-shortcode-atts-array-do)
[link3](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119294/pass-boolean-value-in-shortcode)

they all talk about never using **extract** and **echo** in shortcodes this is so bad practice in wordpress code and using **$atts** and **$return** instead.

which casts doubt on the effectiveness of this code...

**My question now is  :** how to make this shortcode **[parent-child] working with link=false**  , and  no extract and echo in shortcode.

thank you if you **understood what i'm talking about** and knows how to make it more **respectful of wordpress standards**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to make this shortcode [parent-child] working with link=false , and no extract in shortcode.

You can never pass boolean value as shortcode parameter, rather it should be treated as string. Your comparison over the param `link` value `false` should be used as `'false'` (string).

```php
add_shortcode( 'parent-child', 'taxonomy_hierarchy' );
function taxonomy_hierarchy( $atts ){
    // Don't extract, rather parse shortcode params with defaults.
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'link' => 'true',
        'taxonomy' => 'property_city'
    ), $atts, 'parent-child' );

    // Check the $atts parameters and their typecasting.
    var_dump( $atts );

    global $post;
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $atts['taxonomy'] );

    /* You can pass conditions here to override
     * $link based on certain conditions. If it's
     * a single post, current user is editor, etc.
     */

    ob_start();
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
        if( $term->parent != 0 ){
            $parent_term = get_term( $term->parent, $taxonomy );
            if ($atts['link'] !== 'false') {
                printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>, ', esc_url( get_term_link($parent_term) ), $parent_term->name );
            } else {
                echo $parent_term->name . ', ';
            }
        }

        if ($atts['link'] !== 'false') {
            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( get_term_link($term) ), $term->name );
        } else {
            echo $term->name;
        }
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

> no echo in shortcode

It's not about using `echo`, you are asked to not echo output within shortcode. Rather, you should return it as WordPress will replace shortcode with your output value. Here, you are buffering your output using `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` functions and returning it. Which is just fine, and commonly used techniques.

Comment: Millions thank you Shazzad !
for this correction and clear explanation.
I am new to the world of php but I try not to make things too complicated to understand :) if you want to take a look [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/378112/wordpress-auto-rename-and-fill-attributes-on-upload-to-cpt) and [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/381108/more-elegant-loading-container-like-google-chrome) I have been stuck on these codes for a while. I know the code is working but I'm having trouble with some functions